# Pan Tilt Bracket for CCTV

Tags: protocols

[image]How can I change the Address of the pan tilt bracket for CCTV (Pelco-D Protocol) with a PC(USB to RS485)? Any software available? I tried with my HIKVISION DVR but couldn't change the default address "1". Command 20, 26 works but the saving sequence- 25 preset , assigned address say "5" preset, 26 preset doesn't work. Don't want to buy a separate controller keyboard/joystick only for this address change.

Comment: “The” pan tilt bracket? You’ll have to give us at least a reference...